# Applying CSS to Struts in a JSP page

Tags: html, css, jsp, struts2

I'm trying to add css to my website but It just load half of the page and stop. Anyone have an idea about this problem? Thank you so much.
It stopped loading right before the confirm textfield, the whole page was loaded correctly.
Sorry if the code is hard to read. I'm new to coding.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HVH's Store</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css">
    <style>
        html, body {
            position: relative;
        }
        ul.navbar-hungdtq > li {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .navbar{
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .navbar-footer > li {
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .login-form{
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .swiper-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .swiper-slide {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            background: #fff;

            /* Center slide text vertically */
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        div.swiper-slide > img {
            width: 600px;
            height: 800px;
        }
        .container-hungdtq{
            background: white;
            padding: 1%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10vh;
        }
        .main-hungdtq{
            background: white;
            padding-top: 1%;

        }

        .mega-menu {
            position: absolute;
            padding: 10px 0px;
            width: 110vh;
            height: 82vh;
            border-radius: 0;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        .mega-menu li {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            font-size: 0.94rem;
            padding: 3px 0px;
        }

        .mega-menu li.mega-menu-column {
            margin-right: 20px;
            width: 20vh;
        }

        .mega-menu .nav-header {
            padding: 0 !important;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        li.mega-menu-column > ul > li > a{
            color: #777;
        }
        li.mega-menu-column > ul {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        li.mega-menu-column > ul > li {
            font-size: 1.5vh;
        }

        .well{
            padding: 8vh 0vh;
        }

        h4 {
            font-size: 8vh;
        }
        /* Profile container */
        .profile {
            margin: 20px 0;
        }

        /* Profile sidebar */
        .profile-sidebar {
            padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
            background: #fff;
        }

        .profile-userpic img {
            float: none;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
            -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
            border-radius: 50% !important;
        }

        .profile-usertitle {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .profile-usertitle-name {
            color: #5a7391;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin-bottom: 7px;
        }

        .profile-usertitle-job {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #5b9bd1;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        .profile-userbuttons {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .profile-userbuttons .btn {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: 600;
            padding: 6px 15px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .profile-userbuttons .btn:last-child {
            margin-right: 0px;
        }

        .profile-usermenu {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        .profile-usermenu ul li {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f4f7;
        }

        .profile-usermenu ul li:last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        .profile-usermenu ul li a {
            color: #93a3b5;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        .profile-usermenu ul li a i {
            margin-right: 8px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .profile-usermenu ul li a:hover {
            background-color: #fafcfd;
            color: #5b9bd1;
        }

        .profile-usermenu ul li.active {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        .profile-usermenu ul li.active a {
            color: #5b9bd1;
            background-color: #f6f9fb;
            border-left: 2px solid #5b9bd1;
            margin-left: -2px;
        }

        /* Profile Content */
        .profile-content {
            padding: 20px;
            background: #fff;
            min-height: 460px;
        }

        input.hidden {
            position: absolute;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        #profile-image1 {
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border:2px solid #03b1ce ;}
        .tital{ font-size:16px; font-weight:500;}
        .bot-border{ border-bottom:1px #f8f8f8 solid;  margin:5px 0  5px 0} 
    </style>
    <s:head/>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Tool bar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top main-hungdtq">
        <div class="container-hungdtq">
            <div class="col-md-1" >
                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#">
                    <img style="max-width: 100px; margin-top: -50px;" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/6f/55/e1/6f55e1ddd3d428846ab97062f9af3ad8--line-logo-design-logo-k.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <form action="SearchForBookAction">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tìm kiếm" name="search">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>
            <s:set var="username" value="%{#session.USERNAME}"/>
            <s:set var="fail" value="%{#session.failed}"></s:set>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-md-4">
                <s:if test="%{#username == null || #username == ''}">
                    <li class="col-md-3"><a href="signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Đăng ký</a></li>
                    <!--Login-->
                    <li class="col-md-3">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Đăng nhập</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu login-form" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                            <form action="login" class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Username: </label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter username" name="username">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label>Password: </label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Đăng nhập" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 25%">
                            </form>
                            <script>
                                <s:if test="%{#fail != null}">
                                alert("Wrong username or password!");
                                </s:if>
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!--End of Login-->
                </s:if>
                <s:if test="%{#username != null || #username == ''}">
                    <li class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in">Welcome, <s:property value="#username"/></span></a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-4"><a href="<s:url action="RedirectToProfileAction"/>"><span claRedirectToProfileActionss="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Tài khoản của tôi</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
                        </s:if>
            </ul>    
        </div>

        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <ul class="navbar-hungdtq nav navbar-nav row" style="width: 100%;">
                <li class="col-md-1"></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">SÁCH BÁN CHẠY</a></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">KHUYẾN MÃI HOT</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown col-md-2">
                    <a class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">KHO SÁCH<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-menu">
                        <li class="mega-menu-column">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="nav-header">Khoa học kỹ thuật</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tin học</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Y học</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Điện - điện tử</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Cơ khí</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mega-menu-column">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="nav-header">Kinh tế</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Quản trị - Lãnh đạo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Nhân vật - Bài học kinh doanh</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Khởi nghiệp - Làm giàu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Marketing - Bán hàng</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tài chính - Ngân hàng</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mega-menu-column">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="nav-header">Thiếu nhi</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Truyện tranh</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Truyện đọc</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tô màu - Luyện chữ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Kiến thức bách khoa</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Manga</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mega-menu-column">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="nav-header">Văn học trong nước</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Phóng sự - Ký sự</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Nhân vật văn học</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Thơ ca</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tiểu thuyết lịch sử</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tiểu thuyết lãng mạng</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="mega-menu-column">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="nav-header">Văn học nước ngoài</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Cổ tích - Thần thoại</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Truyện lịch sử</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Truyện ngắn</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Truyện trinh thám</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Vụ án</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">SỰ KIỆN SÁCH</a></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">KHO SÁCH CŨ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!--End of Navigation bar-->
    </nav>
    <!--End of Tool bar-->

    <!--Body-->
    <div  style="padding-top: 180px ">
        <div class="container">
        <s:form cssClass="well form-horizontal" action="register" method="get"  id="contact_form" theme="simple">
                <center><h4>REGISTER</h4></center>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tên của bạn:</label>  
                    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <s:textfield  name="name" placeholder="" cssClass="form-control"  type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>  
                    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <s:textfield  name="username" placeholder="Tên tài khoản" cssClass="form-control"  type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Mật khẩu:</label> 
                    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <s:textfield name="password" placeholder="" cssClass="form-control"  type="password"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Xác nhận:</label> 
                    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <s:textfield name="confirm "placeholder=" mật khẩu của bạn" cssClass="form-control"  type="password"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Pick -->
                <div class="form-group"> 
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Giới tính</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
                            <s:combobox label="Hãy chọn giới tính của bạn" name="gender" cssClass="form-control selectpicker"
                                        list="{'1':'Nam', '2':'Nu'}
                                        "/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
                    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                            <s:textfield name="email" placeholder="Địa chỉ E-Mail" cssClass="form-control"  type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Địa chỉ</label>  
                    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <s:textfield  name="address" placeholder="Địa chỉ của bạn" cssClass="form-control"  type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Số điện thoại</label>  
                    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                            <s:textfield name="phone" placeholder="(08)" cssClass="form-control" type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-4"><br>
                        <s:submit type="submit" cssClass="btn btn-warning" name="Đăng ký" /><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </s:form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of Body-->

    <!--Footer-->
    <footer class="footer">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <ul class="navbar-footer nav navbar-nav row" style="width: 100%;">
                <li class="col-md-1"></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">VỀ CHÚNG TÔI</a></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">LIÊN HỆ</a></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">ĐỊA ĐIỂM</a></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">ĐÓNG GÓP Ý KIẾN</a></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">CHÍNH SÁCH</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>
    <!--End of Footer-->
</body>
```

[This is the image of my website after being loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY4tc.png)

Comment: where? which line?

Comment: Can you try `<s:password>` instead of `<s:textfield type="password"/>`. Shouldn't make any difference, but worth trying.

Comment: there s no difference :D But thank you for supporting

Comment: Do you have a version of the page without any CSS? Can you share it?

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your app. See server logs for exceptions, use dev tool in your browser to see what fails.

Comment: change `list="{'1':'Nam', '2':'Nu'}"` to `list="#{'1':'Nam', '2':'Nu'}"`